# Show that $\vec{u}$ + c$\vec{v}$ is a solution to A$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an $m × n$ matrix. Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be solutions of A$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$ and let $c$ be a scalar. Show that $\vec{u}$ + $c$$\vec{v}$ is a solution to A$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$.

I have substituted $\vec{x}$ for $\vec{u}$ + $c$$\vec{v}$ and got $A$($\vec{u}$ + $c$$\vec{v}$),  I then distributed $A$ which got me $A$$\vec{u}$ + $A$$c$$\vec{v}$ I assume since both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are solutions then $A$$\vec{u}$ = $\vec{0}$ and $A$$\vec{v}$ = $\vec{0}$, so $A$$\vec{u}$ + $A$$c$$\vec{v}$ can be simplified into $\vec{0}$ + $c$$\vec{0}$ = $\vec{0}$.

Please let me know if I am approaching this problem correctly. Thank you.

Comment: looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, indeed since $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are in the nullspace of $A$ also their linear combination $\vec w=\vec{u}+c\vec v$, as any other linear combination of vectors in the null space, is a vector in the nullspace of $A$ and therefore $A\vec w=0$ as you have properly proved, indeed for $\vec u_i \in N(A)$ we have

$$A\sum_i c_i \vec u_i = \sum_i c_i A\vec u_i =\sum_i \vec 0=\vec 0$$